# CVS Projects to SVN Master Project and Modules

Tags: svn, cvs

we want to convert a number of existing multiple CVS projects to a single maven/SVN modules project. We are not concerned with History, so any history that comes over is a benefit, but not a requirement. Also, the SVN is a requirement, the option for git, or some other SCM is not an option.  I’ve read the FAQ and docs on cvs2svn, but cvs2svn seems to be suited as a 1-for-1 project to project conversion.  I couldn’t find anything on CVS to SVN/Modules.  Our CVS projects are organized as one main Web project and one or more Java projects that the Web Project utilizes.  I would ‘like’ to model these conversions using one of our existing maven/SVN projects which use a master project and multiple modules…this makes code management MUCH easier in our development cycles.  It also seems to flow well with our standard development toolset of Eclipse/Maven/SVN and the Nexus repository.

Details are :

One of our typical CVS Projects :

```
./web-project/
./java-project/
```

What we want is ( This is how our existing maven/SVN project is organized) :

```
./master-project/ 
    ./branches/ 
    ./tags/
    ./trunk/ 
        ./web-module/ 
        ./java-module/
```

My question is what (if any) is the best way to convert?

My initial thought was the following :

- Use cvs2svn to convert the CVS web-project.
- svn load web-cvs-dump-file as new SVN project, use command line option with new master-project-name.
- Manually commit the java project as a new module under the master.

Comment: I'm confused. If you're not concerned about history, could you not just copy the latest files and commit?

Comment: Yes, trying that now...It's taking surprising longer than I expected.  Being a noob to maven, I'm thinking the archetype of quickstart was not the right choice.